# How could I set multi-line text in an Excel textbox using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Here my code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];
    xlApp.Visible = true;

    Excel.Shape textBox = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
        10 + 10 + 10, 36, 600, 100);
    textBox.TextFrame.Characters(System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing).Text
        = "testing";

    xlApp.ActiveWindow.Activate();
    xlApp.UserControl = true;
    ws = null;
    wb = null;
    xlApp = null;
}
```

But with this code I only can add one line text "testing":

```
---------------------------------
|Testing                        |
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

Now I want to add 3 line text, like this:

```
---------------------------------
|Test1                          |
|Test2                          |
|Test3                          |
---------------------------------
```

Somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Environment.NewLine` might be the constant you are looking for to separate your 3 strings.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will vote your answer 10 times if I can

Comment: Also, you might need to enable TextWrap on the cell to get it to display this way.